# How to get ZIP code from Company using HubSpot API (Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, hubspot, hubspot-crm, hubspot-api

I am new with the HubSpot API and was working with the sample code from the HubSpot Academy tutorials, and would like to narrow down the API call to the ZIP code. How would I do this using Node.js?

The example is from this course:
https://academy.hubspot.com/courses/introduction-to-hubspot-apis

I would like to be able to get the ZIP code from a company, but there are no clear instructions anywhere I could find online.

Answer (score 0):

See the HubSpot API call for getting companies [here](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/companies). Once you get the company, the zip code should be in the properties attribute.